# How to calculate a value between two dates in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, finance

I'm trying to calculate the annual returns of a trading strategy in R. I've tried various methods but keep getting inconsistent results.

Here is some test data;

```
             CumBal
2007-01-03 1000000.0
2007-01-04 1000000.0
2007-01-05 1114999.4
2007-01-08  889999.4
2007-01-09 1109997.6
2007-01-10 1179998.8
2007-01-11 1229998.8
2007-01-12 1050000.0
2007-01-16  979998.8
2007-01-17 1284997.6
        ...
2018-05-10 2161996.3
2018-05-11 2161996.3
2018-05-14 2161996.3
2018-05-15 2161996.3
2018-05-16 2137496.0
2018-05-17 2128995.8
2018-05-18 2128995.8
2018-05-21 2128995.8
2018-05-22 2128995.8
```

The overall results of the strategy are;

```
                            Results
Balance                1000000.0000
Final Balance          2133996.1000
Net-Profit             1133996.1000
CAGR                         0.0681
Total Return (%)             1.1340
Sharpe Ratio                 0.0000
Profit Factor                1.1432
Max Loss on Inv %           -0.1100
Max loss on Inv £     -664999.4000
Total Number of Trade      259.0000
% of Win Trades              0.2432
Win:Loss                     0.5207
Ulcer Peformance Index       0.0000
```

The problem I'm confronted with is in calculating the monthly and annual returns.  I want to do this to determine the standard deviation of annual and monthly returns to calculate the Sharpe Ratio. I've tried using the `PerformanceAnalytics` package however get an inconsistent result with the actual performance;

```
table.CalendarReturns(a.1)
      Jan Feb Mar  Apr  May Jun Jul  Aug Sep   Oct  Nov Dec CumBal
2007  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0   0   0  0.0   0   0.0  0.0 0.0     NA
2008  0.0   0   0  0.0 12.7   0   0  0.0   0 -18.9  0.0 0.0   -8.6
2009  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0   0   0  0.0   0   0.0  0.0 0.0     NA
2010 -1.2   0   0  0.0  0.0   0   0  0.0   0   0.0  0.0 0.0   -1.2
2011  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.7   0   0  0.0   0   0.0  0.0 0.0    0.7
2012  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0   0   0  0.0   0   0.0  0.0 0.0     NA
2013  0.0   0   0 -0.5  0.0   0   0  0.0   0   0.0 -0.5 0.4   -0.5
2014  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0   0   0  0.3   0   0.0  0.0 0.0    0.3
2015  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0   0   0  0.0   0   0.0  0.0 0.0     NA
2016 -3.8   0   0 -0.6  0.0   0   0 -0.5   0   0.0  0.3 0.0   -4.5
2017  0.0   0   0  0.0  0.0   0   0  0.0   0   0.0  0.0 0.0     NA
2018 -0.7   0   0  0.0  0.0   0   0   NA  NA    NA   NA  NA   -0.7
```

I've then tried a suggestion from a member on the forum, which was to use `Return.calculaute()`, then `to.monthly` and then `table.CalendarReturns()`. However the `to.monthly` somehow outputs the result below, therefore `table.CalendarReturns()` doesn't work;

```
a.1 <- data.frame(a.1)
    a.z <- Return.calculate(a.1)
    a.q <- to.monthly(a.z)
```

Result is ...

```
> a.q
             a.z.Open     a.z.High      a.z.Low    a.z.Close
Jan 2007  0.000000000 0.3112236464 -0.201793831  0.000000000
Feb 2007  0.000000000 0.0000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
                           ...
Apr 2018  0.000000000 0.0000000000 -0.047367213  0.000000000
May 2018  0.000000000 0.0000000000 -0.011332235  0.000000000
Jun 2018  0.000000000 0.0023486660  0.000000000  0.000000000
Jul 2018  0.000000000 0.0000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000
```

Comment: Using the `PerformanceAnalytics` package, treat `CumBal` as prices and use `Return.calculate` to get daily returns.  Then use  `to.monthly` to convert the daily returns to monthly.  `table.CalendarReturns` can then be used to properly display the monthly return table.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I've tried;
        `a.1 <- data.frame(a.1)
 a.z <- Return.calculate(a.1)
 a.q <- to.monthly(a.z)
 table.CalendarReturns(a.q)`

And `table.CalendarReturns` doesn't work because `to.monthly` does this; `> a.q
             a.z.Open     a.z.High      a.z.Low    a.z.Close
Jan 2007  0.000000000 0.3112236464 -0.201793831  0.000000000
Feb 2007  0.000000000 0.0000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000`
I'll edit the post to included this now. Any thoughts?

Comment: I hope your input data is in `xts` format. Then `table.CalendarReturns(df_in_xts_format)` should provide you the desired monthly/ annual returns table. If this doesn't help then you may want to update your post with the sample data using `dput(df)` so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Besides verifying that your data is in `xts` format,  take at look at your data values.  Your 2018 results show little change and some days with no change at all.  If this is typical of most of your data, then the `a.q` results could be correct.  Also `table.CalendarReturns` by default shows only one digit so smaller returns would show as zero.  Finally we need a correction in the monthly table input.  Try `table.CalendarReturns(a.q[,4], digits = 4)`.   This would be easier to work through if we had a couple of months of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a.1=xts(CumBal)

# this functions needs monthly returns
table.CalendarReturns(Return.calculate(to.monthly(a.1,drop.time=F)[,4]))

# for annualized Sharpe and SD
a.z <- Return.calculate(a.1) #daily

# all sample
table.AnnualizedReturns(a.z, scale = NA, Rf = 0, geometric = TRUE,
                        digits = 4)
library(lubridate)  # for year
# Columns are "Annualized Return" "Annualized Std Dev" "Annualized Sharpe (Rf=0%)"
# set a different value of daily risk free rate if needed (Rf)
do.call("rbind",
        tapply(a.z,year(a.z),function(xz)table.AnnualizedReturns(xz, scale = NA, Rf = 0, geometric = TRUE,
                        digits = 4)))

do.call("rbind",
        tapply(a.z,as.yearmon(time(a.z)),function(xz)table.AnnualizedReturns(xz, scale = NA, Rf = 0, geometric = TRUE,
                                                        digits = 4)))
```

You will get something similar to this:

```
# > table.AnnualizedReturns(a.z, scale = NA, Rf = 0, geometric = TRUE,
# +                         digits = 4)
                               x
# Annualized Return         0.3398
# Annualized Std Dev        0.6307
# Annualized Sharpe (Rf=0%) 0.5388

#"Annualized Return" "Annualized Std Dev"  "Annualized Sharpe (Rf=0%)"

# > do.call("rbind",
#           +         tapply(a.z,as.yearmon(time(a.z)),function(xz)table.AnnualizedReturns(xz, scale = NA, Rf = 0, geometric = TRUE,
#                                                                                          +                                                         digits = 4)))
# [,1]   [,2]     [,3]
# mar 2007  -0.6389 0.5401  -1.1828
# abr 2007   0.1660 0.6364   0.2608
# ...
# abr 2009  -0.9403 0.7410  -1.2689
# mai 2009   0.5594 0.4922   1.1365
# jun 2009  -0.2650 0.6384  -0.4151
# ...
# jul 2011   2.4026 0.6563   3.6610
# ago 2011   0.0385 0.6570   0.0586
# set 2011   5.1043 0.6925   7.3708
# ...
# abr 2018  -0.9262 0.7404  -1.2509
# mai 2018  -0.4648 0.7755  -0.5993
```